# Delphi 10 IDE 'false' is not a valid boolean value

Tags: delphi, ide

We are migrating an old Delphi 2007 application to Delphi 10.3. The app uses a specific BPL written just for it (it is a standard in our company)

The BPL compiles fine, but after installing it, Delphi 10 shows an error box
[image: Error after installing the BPL]

The IDE hangs continuously showing the message. If I click "Ok" the error pops again and again even if neither mouse or keyboard are used. Must kill using task manager

The complete text is

```
[50091D9D]{rtl260.bpl  } System.SysUtils.ConvertErrorFmt (Line 5610, "System.SysUtils.pas" + 1) + $10
[500941FF]{rtl260.bpl  } System.SysUtils.StrToBool (Line 9000, "System.SysUtils.pas" + 2) + $14
[2064C6A5]{coreide260.bpl} MSBBuildConfiguration.TBuildConfiguration.GetBoolean (Line 458, "MSBBuildConfiguration.pas" + 3) + $7
[2064C5D2]{coreide260.bpl} MSBBuildConfiguration.TBuildConfiguration.GetBoolean (Line 441, "MSBBuildConfiguration.pas" + 0) + $6
[21CEC783]{delphicoreide260.bpl} BaseDelphiProject.TDelphiCodeIPackageProject.IsDesignPackage (Line 5942, "BaseDelphiProject.pas" + 6) + $A
[21CA6143]{delphicoreide260.bpl} PkgContainers.TStdPackageProjectContainer.GetIndex (Line 155, "PkgContainers.pas" + 2) + $20
[206FDA8A]{coreide260.bpl} ProjectFrm.TProjectManagerForm.ProjectTree2GetImageIndex (Line 1844, "ProjectFrm.pas" + 22) + $14
[212DE51C]{vclide260.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.DoGetImageIndex (Line 19089, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 8) + $19
[212E0B77]{vclide260.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.GetImageIndex (Line 20601, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 6) + $26
[212EA3F1]{vclide260.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.PaintTree (Line 27617, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 221) + $27
[212E35B7]{vclide260.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.Paint (Line 22316, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 22) + $10
[50D201F3]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TCustomControl.PaintWindow (Line 14241, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 6) + $5
[50D19F11]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.PaintHandler (Line 10362, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) + $14
[50D1A6F8]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WMPaint (Line 10563, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 6) + $5
[50D2018D]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TCustomControl.WMPaint (Line 14230, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 2) + $4
[212DAFB1]{vclide260.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.WMPaint (Line 16924, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 8) + $4
[50D15292]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7420, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[5005FDDF]{rtl260.bpl  } System.TObject.Dispatch (Line 18324, "System.pas" + 11) + $0
[0DAE8E82]{themeloader260.bpl} Idetheme.Vclstylehooks.TIDEStyleHook.WndProc + $7A
[500679A8]{rtl260.bpl  } System.@IntfClear (Line 38159, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[0DAE893B]{themeloader260.bpl} Idetheme.Vclstylehooks.TIDEStyleHook.HandleMessage + $B7
[500679A8]{rtl260.bpl  } System.@IntfClear (Line 38159, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[50063FD8]{rtl260.bpl  } System.@FinalizeArray (Line 32812, "System.pas" + 144) + $0
[0DB21CC2]{themeloader260.bpl} Idetheme.Stylemanager.TIDEThemeStyleEngine.UnRegisterSysStyleHook + $106
[50D197BC]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10122, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 10) + $48
[50D19D47]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10278, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 166) + $6
[50063194]{rtl260.bpl  } System.@UStrSetLength (Line 30446, "System.pas" + 27) + $0
[212E57B4]{vclide260.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.WndProc (Line 23720, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 32) + $4
[50D19314]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9977, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[501796A4]{rtl260.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 17932, "System.Classes.pas" + 11) + $2
[12EC238A]{CnWizards_D103R.DLL} Unknown function at __dbk_fcall_wrapper + $60672
[50063EA4]{rtl260.bpl  } System.@FinalizeRecord (Line 32510, "System.pas" + 41) + $0
[26CA255C]{JvRuntimeDesign260.bpl} JvDesignImp.TJvDesignSelector.RemoveFromSelection + $C
[5005A285]{rtl260.bpl  } System.@ReallocMem (Line 4913, "System.pas" + 21) + $0
[50063194]{rtl260.bpl  } System.@UStrSetLength (Line 30446, "System.pas" + 27) + $0
[212CC833]{vclide260.bpl} IDEVirtualTrees.TVirtualTreeHintWindow.IsHintMsg (Line 7100, "IDEVirtualTrees.pas" + 7) + $13
[50E6EC33]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10747, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50E6EC76]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10777, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50E6EFA9]{vcl260.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10915, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
[0051D022]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 214, "" + 7) + $7
```

If we cheat the IDE by first running it, manually installing the .bpl file no error is shown, but then, we can not open ***any*** project but the IDE responds: menus, mouse and keyboard but loading any project triggers the error. Even creating a new project triggers it

[image: Error loading project]

I've searched for days without finding a single page targeting this problem.

Any idea why this strange behavior is happening and how to solve it? Other programs with this approach (an application specific BPL) have no problem, but this is the first we are migrating from 2007

`Edit:` I tried deleting the .dproj file and openning the .dpr. That will force to create a new default one. No luck. Same behavior

Comment: Is your BPL perhaps built with custom locale and thus `StrToBool` might be using localized string representation of Boolean values?

Comment: Hard to help when one is not sitting in front of your dev machine but lets give it a go; I assume you still have the old Delphi installed? Did you migrate settings from that version towards the new one? You might have problems with that. I suggest you start to clean-up your new installation. Check your IDE Browsing Paths, Library Paths, DCU Paths etc. Make sure they are not referencing paths that may contain old BPLs, DCUs or old Delphi files. Recreate BOTH the DPK (not dpr) and the DPROJ files of the package from inside the new IDE....

Comment: ...Check your package Paths as well. Make sure it is not outputting to a path that might be shared between the two Delphis. Look at Environment Variables. Your goal is to make sure you are not referencing anything from the old Delphi or old Package. Remember to check through all Build Configurations. Now BUILD properly. Then install manually. Confirm by creating a new blank project and calling something from the BPL. Such issues tend to be unique because of the sometime unique way developers setup their machines. (Uwe's answer below has happened to me as well.)

Comment: ...Remember to also make sure your project that you are migrating is not referencing old paths as well. And also just in case you are one of those; DONT save everything in a single path. Split your packages each one into their own folders and your project in its own. And make have separate output paths. Keep things clean and manageable

Comment: @SilverWarior please post your comment as an answer since that solved the issue. I had a vague idea that the code itself was causing the trouble, since it only appeared after installing the .bpl file but had no clue where to start

Comment: Luckily this was resolved with Delphi 11.3, where True and False are always valid.

Comment: @UweRaabe Could you share more information about where global arrays `TrueBoolStrs` and `FalseBoolStrs` are filled when custom localization is used. Looking at the code I can't figure that out. I do see that if they are empty the default `DefaultTrueBoolStr` and `DefaultFalseBoolStr` are added respectively to specific array. with `VerifyBoolStrArray` procedure if the said arrays are empty.  And how does Delphi 11.3 solve this issue. I'm still on Delphi 11.2.

Comment: @SilverWarior, AFAIK Delphi itself doesn't localize the XxxBoolStrs, but some 3rd party or customer code may do so. In 11.3 there is first a check for the DefaultXxxBoolStr constants before looking into the arrays.